# Slim3 Redirect Not Working?

Tags: redirect, slim

I'm working on a Slim Framework 3 project and can't believe I'm having trouble with redirects. According to their website this should work

```
return $response->withStatus(302)->withHeader("Location", "http://www.google.com");
```

Of course I'd replace, google with my own site, but neither works.

I'm hitting the route, my auth check is working fine, I make it to the redirect return statement, but nothing happens. The page is blank and doesn't redirect. I outputted $response to a file and this is what I saw

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Location: http://www.google.com
```

I've even tried $response->withRedirect() and got the same exact results. What am I missing?

**UPDATE**
I managed to get it working in middleware, but still can't get it working in routes and can't figure out why.

Comment: Could you try it with the status code ``307``? Did you try to redirect in a "post" method?

Comment: @jmattheis It's in a "get" method which renders a phtml template. 307 doesn't work. Here's a simple snippet that I tested:

`$app->get("/", function($req, $res, $args) {
return $this->withStatus(307)->withHeader("Location", "/route");
});`

Comment: Forgot to mention, I did get it working in middleware, but can't get it working within routes. Will update OP.

Comment: In your example in the comments you used ``$this->withStatus..`` but you need to use ``$response``. Could you try it again?

Comment: So this is odd. I'm 100% certain I had $response in my code because that's how I have it in the middleware. I also don't remember seeing any errors which would be thrown by using $this. I'm assuming I just mistyped my example; however it does seem to be working now. I tested with $response->withRedirect() and bam! Anyway, thanks for the help!

Comment: @jmattheis Create an answer with the tip for order purpose.

Comment: @DavidePastore it was only a typo, so it should not be answer worthy, besides that, the code above works fine, so the question should be closed